# Get token from string with elixir

Tags: regex, elixir

I have string that looks like this:

```
link = "<a href=\"http://localhost:5000/confirm/SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YWIAAAsMZAAGc2lnbmVkbgYASDp-jVwB.HqUsytlpKq7h9qEQyjABS1Xv4sgwNFClB-asLYUGfyA\">Potwierdź swoje konto.</a>"
```

How can I get from token that is after `confirm/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with regular expressions like this:

```
link = "<a href=\"http://localhost:5000/confirm/SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YWIAAAsMZAAGc2lnbmVkbgYASDp-jVwB.HqUsytlpKq7h9qEQyjABS1Xv4sgwNFClB-asLYUGfyA\">Potwierdź swoje konto.</a>"

[[_, token]] = Regex.scan(~r/confirm\/(.*?)"/, link)
IO.puts token
```

Output:

```
SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YWIAAAsMZAAGc2lnbmVkbgYASDp-jVwB.HqUsytlpKq7h9qEQyjABS1Xv4sgwNFClB-asLYUGfyA
```

This will work as long as your HTML structure remains exactly the same. Regex cannot parse arbitrary HTML, as you probably know already.